# Is there an efficient way to search dictionaries in a very large file?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a very large (> 10GB) JSON file which contains multiple dictionaries.

Now, I have a list of some other dictionaries.

Let's say I wish to find dictionaries in this file, which matches values for two keys of dictionaries which are on the list, and ultimately extract the value of a third key from such dictionaries. How would I go about doing this?

Currently, this is what I have in mind:

```
def parse(file):
    for l in file:
        yield eval(l)

# list_of_dicts is the list containing the dictionaries

for i in range(0,len(list_of_dicts)):
    generator_of_dicts = parse("huge_file.json")
    for j in generator_of_dicts:
        if j[key1] == list_of_dicts[i][key1] \
        and j[key2] == list_of_dicts[i][key2]:
            print j[key3]
            break
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to be using a *real* database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use jq Bindings for python https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jq
It's a good tool to make queries against JSON.

Otherwise the JSON library of python is good.

But: 10 Gb is a lot - if you do not have the RAM, streaming my be necessary, to jq could be very handy.